# How To Disable Camel HTTP Endpoint Stream Caching When Using Servlet in OSGi

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using an Apache Camel route to receive incoming HTTP traffic using the servlet component.  The route is very simple:

```xml
<camel:route id="peopleSoftServletService" errorHandlerRef="errorHandler">
  <camel:from uri="servlet:///PeopleSoftService" />
  <camel:setHeader headerName="origin">
    <camel:simple>PeopleSoft Server: ${in.header.X-Forwarded-For}</camel:simple>
  </camel:setHeader>
  <camel:inOnly uri="activemq:peoplesoft" />
</camel:route>
```

I'm encountering problems with stream caching.  I'm not explicitly using stream caching, but it seems that by using the servlet component, a Camel HTTPConsumer is implicitly created behind the scenes and registered with the servlet via CamelServlet.connect(HttpConsumer consumer).  What I want to do is disable stream caching (which is turned on by default) on the HTTP endpoint of that consumer, which is typically done using a URI parameter ("disableStreamCache").  Since I'm not explicitly creating that endpoint in this case, I don't know  how to do that.  There's nothing available for the servlet URI parameters to customize the implicit endpoint.

Can this be accomplished in Camel 2.10.0?

Comment: I couldn't get what kind of problem you're facing but, according with the documentation "In Camel 2.0 stream cache is default **disabled** out of the box... So in Camel 2.0 you have to **explicit enable it** if you want to use it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the Stream Caching, you need to setup the exchange property to [disable the stream caching](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http/helper/HttpHelper.java#L184), but it's impossible to set the exchange property from the HttpConsumer, so I just created a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8821) for it and submit a quick fix for it shortly, you can just back port the patch yourself as we don't provide the community support of camel 2.10.x anymore.

Comment: Thanks Willem.  I've back-ported your patch, and the HttpConsumer no longer attempts stream caching on this route.

Comment: The link died... this is why this is a bad habit to simply post a link without the solution.